# How to Add google doc viewer in mvc4 Applicaton?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am beginner in programming. My problem is, I want to show `PDF` files in `Google Doc Viewer` in my website page. I put my `PDF` files in folder named as `Bullettin`, it is in `App_Data` folder.

How can I view this `PDF` file in my website through `Google Doc Viewer` using `C# MVC4` application?

i used the following code in view page
 http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://localhost:3907/App_Data/Bullettin/JCI.pdf&embedded=true" target="_blank" class="embed">View

Comment: i put the url in http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://url &embedded=true" target="_blank" class="embed"> in many ways. but i got the "sorry, we were unable to find the document at the original source.varify the document still exist.you also try to download the original document by clicking here" message

Comment: You need to URL encode the URL before passing to Google Docs Viewer.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the following url for embed: `http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://localhost:3907/App_Data/Bullettin/JCI.pdf` for previews

and: `<a href="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://localhost:3907/App_Data/Bullettin/JCI.pdf&embedded=true" target="_blank">Preview</a>`

for links, and finally:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://localhost:3907/App_Data/Bullettin/JCI.pdf&embedded=true"></iframe>
```

For Iframes.

Well, localhost will not work for you, so get your project on a live server or use an IP address to link your server.

Good luck with it.

Comment: How can we enable search in document for Google Doc Viewer?