# how to show the doc, xls, pdf and txt file in iframe?

Tags: html, asp.net

Using "frame" of html for showing the files but only show the PDFs and text file in "frame", doc and x ls files are downloaded instead of showing.

Following is the sample code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="generator"
    content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 (experimental) for Windows https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5/tree/c63cc39" />
    <title>Open Word in Iframe</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div align="center">
      <table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td width="25%" align="left" valign="top">
            <a href="doc1.pdf" target="awindow">Doc 1</a>
            <br />
            <a href="doc2.doc" target="awindow">Doc 2</a>
            <br />
            <a href="doc3.text" target="awindow">Doc 3</a>
          </td>
          <td width="75%" align="center" valign="top">
            <iframe name="awindow" frameborder="2" width="580" height="440" src="doc.txt"></iframe>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure MIME types for your web server in order to avoid downloading of those file types, when the remote client requests them directly (i.e. not through your web scripts).

.doc and .xls file types are probably not configured by default, so they default to a MIME type which is simply downloaded instead of displayed in the browser. Btw, the standard browsers don't know by default how to display Microsoft-specific file types, so you might need an extension/plugin/flash object to display it properly.

Comment: You can try to provide a link, combined with the google doc viewer base url, which would make google doc open that file and display it as html. More info here: https://docs.google.com/viewer

Comment: there is no info at that url.

Comment: you can see some examples in this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953229/how-to-add-google-doc-viewer-in-mvc4-applicaton

Answer (score 1):

To display Word/Excell/PDF etc. file without plugins, use the Google Drive Viewer.
Instead of `<iframe src="https://your-url.com/file.doc">` use `<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://your-url.com/file.doc">` and the files will load.